# при выводе данных в Excel из программы необходимо убрать первый столбец "Код поставщика"

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, export

Созданы два метода: ExporttoExcel и метод запроса на Export.
Первый метод формирует расположение элементов таблицы с помощью списка, нужно исправить только код данного метода.
При выводе в Excel данных из таблицы появляется так же первый атрибут "Код поставщика", его необходимо убрать, чтобы отчет был полностью корректен.
Код на языке C#:

```
    private void ExporttoExcel(DataTable dt, Excel.Worksheet sheet)
    {
        int _excelHeader = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            _excelHeader = 1;
            for (int j = 1; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                sheet.Cells[i + 2, _excelHeader] = dt.Rows[i][j];
                _excelHeader++;
            }

        }
        _excelHeader = 1;
        foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
        {
            sheet.Cells[1, _excelHeader] = column.ColumnName;
            _excelHeader++;
        }
    
        sheet.Columns.ColumnWidth = 30;
        sheet.Columns.HorizontalAlignment = Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignLeft;
    }
```

Comment: Так, и в чем проблема? Даже банальное `if (column.ColumnName == "....") continue;` должно решить ваш вопрос.

Comment: вывод в Excel происходит следующим образом: "Код поставщика", "Организация", "Описание", ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не очень понимаю, зачем в цикле по столбцам используется переменная _excelHeader, но попробуйте так:

```
    private void ExporttoExcel(DataTable dt, Excel.Worksheet sheet)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                if (dt.Columns[j].ColumnName == "Код поставщика")
                    continue;
                sheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dt.Rows[i][j];
            }

        }

        int _excelHeader = 1;
        foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
        {
            if (column.ColumnName == "Код поставщика")
                continue;
            sheet.Cells[1, _excelHeader] = column.ColumnName;
            _excelHeader++;
        }
    
        sheet.Columns.ColumnWidth = 30;
        sheet.Columns.HorizontalAlignment = Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignLeft;
    }
```